# Impact force with unknown deformations or time duration?

Tags: stresses, applied-mechanics, dynamics, deformation

I expected to find more documentation on analytical solutions to determine the contact force between bodies, where deformations ($\delta = \delta_{1} + \delta_{2}$) and impact time ($t = t_{f} - t_{i}$) are unknown.

> The time interval begins at contact between bodies (with $m_{1}$, $v_{1,i}$, and $m_{2}$, $v_{2,i}$) and ends at the instant $v_{f} = v_{1,f} = v_{2,f}$.  Without deformation, $d = 0$: $d = \frac {v'-v}{2}*t$ and $\mathrm {dP} = F\mathrm {dt}$ require the time interval $t = 0$ and $F \to \infty$.
>
> **Avoiding deformation analysis, is it possible to apply $\lim_{t \to 0}$ or $\lim_{d \to 0}$ to calculate a finite, average contact force?**
>
> **If not, how is deformation ($\delta = \delta_{1} + \delta_{2}$) or time duration ($t$) calculated?**

While accurate solutions are readily obtained by Finite Element Methods (continuum mechanics), as shown, **do analytical solutions exist?**

[image: FEA]

Many engineering texts do contain partial solutions (for axial, bending, and torsional impact), where deformation is calculated for the impacted body only- **they do not account for deformation in both bodies**.  This results is a conservative estimate of contact force and stress.
Contact forces and stresses are well documented (ex. [Contact Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_mechanics)); however, they require that contact forces are known.  Please explain how these might be introduced to solve for deformation in both bodies.

---

My incomplete solution follows.  I am interested in critiques and/or practical, analytical approaches to this type of problem.

Conservation of Momentum: $$m_{1}(v_{f} - v_{1,i}) = m_{2}(v_{f} - v_{2,i}) \; \Rightarrow \; \therefore v_{f} = \frac {m_{1}v_{1,i}-m_{2}v_{2,i}}{m_{1}-m_{2}}$$

Without a known force, deformation is solved with respect to energy.  For the ideal case, bodies are linear elastic (with stiffness $k = \frac{EA}{L}$ where $E$ is the Modulus of Elasticity, $A$ is contact area, and $L$ is the length perpendicular to contact area).  Certainly, these large assumptions result in error; regardless, they allow for an estimate.

$$\Delta E_{Kinetic} = E_{Deform}$$

$$[\frac {1}{2}m_{1}v_{1,i}^2 + \frac {1}{2}m_{2}v_{2,i}^2]_\text{i} - [\frac {1}{2}(m_{1} + m_{2})v_{f}^2]_\text{f} = \frac {1}{2}k_{1}\delta_{1} + \frac {1}{2}k_{2}\delta_{2}$$

I am unable to complete the system of equations- I know that both bodies:

- Deform during the same time interval
- Have equal contact forces/surface stresses

**Can this problem be solved analytically?**